# Откуда пошло слово ЛЕПО?

Tags: этимология

Неужели слово ЛЕПО (ЛЕПОТА) русским людям надо было у кого-то занимать, чтобы потом использовать в своем обиходе?

ЛЕПО - старое русское слово - красиво. ЛЕПЫЙ, ЛЕПОТА, ЛЕПОСТЬ = красивость, красота. В том же кусте мы имеем наше главное слово ЛЮБО!

Тогда как же этот корень оказался в латинском языке? LEPOS - красота, прелесть, изящество, LEPIDE - прекрасно, великолепно, мило, LEPOR - очарование, LEPIDUS - изящный, милый, прелестный, прекрасный, PER-LEPIDE - очень мило.

В греческом это λεπτός (ΛΕΠΤΟΣ, т.е. ЛЕПТОС) - изысканный, тактичный.

Вроде бы до 10 века наши предки с Европой так тесно не соприкасались, чтобы у них появилось горячее желание заменить свои исконные слова иностранными, т.е. чужими. А ведь таких заимствований в русском языке, как уверяют языковеды, тысячи!

Как удалось европейцам внедрить в головы русичей тысячи слов из своего словаря?

При этом, считать, что русские, мол, донесли эти слова из индоевропейского тоже будет неправильно. Слишком много времени прошло с того момента, когда индоевропейские народы разделились.

За прошедшие тысячи лет ничего бы общего между древними и современными языками не осталось.

Comment: Уважаемый, мы все знаем, что Россия – родина слонов, а человек произошёл от русского. Не трудитесь.

Comment: @Федя, наследие праиндоевропейского языка никуда не делось. Это касается и лексики, и грамматики.

Comment: Наследие пра-индоевропейского языка в этом случае - сомнительно.
Слишком большой временной промежуток.

Comment: Нет, не сомнительно. Есть много примеров корней, которые являются общими для большого числа европейских языков.

Comment: Наличие многих примеров общих пра-корней говорит не в пользу теории общего прапредка.
Вспомните - когда распался пра-этнос, из которого вышли так называемые индоевропейцы?

Или Вы считаете, что за тысячи лет могли так девственно сохраниться общие корни в изолированных народах?

Comment: Уважаемый Федя, Вы напрасно умозрительно спорите, т.к. любой серьезный специалист сравнительного языкознания или историк языков Вам скажет, что медицинским фактом является то, что русский (как и другие славянские языки) после латышского и литовского является наиболее близким языком к санскриту (первому письменно зафиксированному древнеарийскому языку). В этом и заключается весь комизм утверждений Фасмера и его нынешних фасмерёнков, что русские тысячи лет заимствовали! Мы просто имеем общие корни с латинским и другими арийскими языками. Заимствования - это относительно свежее явление.

Comment: Уважаемый Федя. Более того, именно в изолированных народах и сохраняются корни. А зачем им меняться? Корни меняются как раз под воздействие смешения. Именно то, что происходит у нас сейчас. (Но у нас сейчас ещё плюс отсутствие защитной государственной политики, в отличие от других стран. Но это другая, хотя и очень интересная тема.) А славяне и балты тысячелетиями оставались жить в своём историческом ареале, можно сказать, прямо с момента распада арийской общности и почти на тех же землях, что и арийцы. Поэтому тут-то всё как раз логично и объяснимо.

Answer (score 5):

нелепый
    Заимств. из ст.-сл. яз., где оно является преф. производным от общеслав. lěpyi «красивый, хороший», того же корня, что лепить и аналогичные смазливый, писать. Нелепый первоначально — «некрасивый» (< «без румян, краски и “лепки”»), затем — «нескладный» и «неразумный».

Comment: Всё верно.

Тогда выходит,  в латинский это слово попало именно из русского. А не наоборот.

Согласны?

Comment: Ну, естественно. Из несуществующего русского. "Верую, ибо нелепо".

Comment: Отчего же не существующего?

Может быть, Вы что-то знаете про древнегреческий? 
Есть ли текстовые оригиналы его, датированные ранее 9-10 века от Р.Х.?

Не удивляйтесь, вопрос не праздный.